# Tooltip - Enter Delay is not working properly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tooltip

i have given enterdelay for tool tip as 1000 and  mouse enter of my treeview for first time i could see the delay. but as in next move to next treeitem was not having any delay. it shows (pops up) immediately.

Am using version 4.8.3. please any solution?

Comment: Check if the child nodes gets the tooltip class on hover. You can check this in dev console.

Comment: yes i can get tool tip for all the nodes, my problem is about only delay - Thanks

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Answer (score 9):

You can use enterNextDelay feature in Material UI API to handle this rather enterDelay to handle delay for the subsequent delay in Tooltip.

```
<Tooltip enterNextDelay={2000} title={'ABC'} arrow='true' classes={{ 'tooltip': classes.customTooltip, arrow: classes.arrow }}>
```

Find more details here:
https://material-ui.com/api/tooltip/#tooltip-api